# tableau extension server could not respond due to malformed response

Tags: node.js, express, tableau-api

I am trying to develop my very first Tableau extension for Tableau server. I am developing it locally.
It is almost a Hello World kind of extension.
When I try to add an extension, it throws me an error "Request Rejected By Server"

[image]

It is a node.js app and running perfectly fine.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const process = require('process');
app.get('/', async function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/datasources.html");
});
const listener = app.listen(3030, () =>{
    console.log("App is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
```

Here is my datasources.html.. This is one of those provided as sample from tableau.. I just added js part of it at the end. All in one file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Datasources Sample</title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <!-- Extensions Library (this will be hosted on a CDN eventually) -->
    <script src="https://extensions.tableauusercontent.com/resources/tableau.extensions.1.latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Our extension's code -->
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- DataSources Table -->
      <div id="dataSources">
        <h4>All DataSources</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="loading" class="table">
            <tbody><tr><td>Loading...</td></tr></tbody>
          </table>         
          <table id="dataSourcesTable" class="table table-striped hidden">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>DataSource Name</th>
                <th>Auto Refresh</th>
                <th style="width: 100%">Info</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- More dataSource info modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="infoModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">DataSource Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="dataSourceDetails" class="modal-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">          
              <table id="detailsTable" class="table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>DataSource Name</td>
                    <td id="nameDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>DataSource Id</td>
                    <td id="idDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Type</td>
                    <td id="typeDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Fields</td>
                    <td id="fieldsDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Connections</td>
                    <td id="connectionsDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Active Tables</td>
                    <td id="activeTablesDetail"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Wrap everything in an anonymous function to avoid polluting the global namespace
(function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    tableau.extensions.initializeAsync().then(function () {
      // Since dataSource info is attached to the worksheet, we will perform
      // one async call per worksheet to get every dataSource used in this
      // dashboard.  This demonstrates the use of Promise.all to combine
      // promises together and wait for each of them to resolve.
      let dataSourceFetchPromises = [];

      // Maps dataSource id to dataSource so we can keep track of unique dataSources.
      let dashboardDataSources = {};

      // To get dataSource info, first get the dashboard.
      const dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;

      // Then loop through each worksheet and get its dataSources, save promise for later.
      dashboard.worksheets.forEach(function (worksheet) {
        dataSourceFetchPromises.push(worksheet.getDataSourcesAsync());
      });

      Promise.all(dataSourceFetchPromises).then(function (fetchResults) {
        fetchResults.forEach(function (dataSourcesForWorksheet) {
          dataSourcesForWorksheet.forEach(function (dataSource) {
            if (!dashboardDataSources[dataSource.id]) { // We've already seen it, skip it.
              dashboardDataSources[dataSource.id] = dataSource;
            }
          });
        });

        buildDataSourcesTable(dashboardDataSources);

        // This just modifies the UI by removing the loading banner and showing the dataSources table.
        $('#loading').addClass('hidden');
        $('#dataSourcesTable').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
      });
    }, function (err) {
      // Something went wrong in initialization.
      console.log('Error while Initializing: ' + err.toString());
    });
  });

  // Refreshes the given dataSource.
  function refreshDataSource (dataSource) {
    dataSource.refreshAsync().then(function () {
      console.log(dataSource.name + ': Refreshed Successfully');
    });
  }

  // Displays a modal dialog with more details about the given dataSource.
  function showModal (dataSource) {
    let modal = $('#infoModal');

    $('#nameDetail').text(dataSource.name);
    $('#idDetail').text(dataSource.id);
    $('#typeDetail').text((dataSource.isExtract) ? 'Extract' : 'Live');

    // Loop through every field in the dataSource and concat it to a string.
    let fieldNamesStr = '';
    dataSource.fields.forEach(function (field) {
      fieldNamesStr += field.name + ', ';
    });

    // Slice off the last ", " for formatting.
    $('#fieldsDetail').text(fieldNamesStr.slice(0, -2));

    dataSource.getConnectionSummariesAsync().then(function (connectionSummaries) {
      // Loop through each connection summary and list the connection's
      // name and type in the info field
      let connectionsStr = '';
      connectionSummaries.forEach(function (summary) {
        connectionsStr += summary.name + ': ' + summary.type + ', ';
      });

      // Slice of the last ", " for formatting.
      $('#connectionsDetail').text(connectionsStr.slice(0, -2));
    });

    dataSource.getActiveTablesAsync().then(function (activeTables) {
      // Loop through each table that was used in creating this datasource
      let tableStr = '';
      activeTables.forEach(function (table) {
        tableStr += table.name + ', ';
      });

      // Slice of the last ", " for formatting.
      $('#activeTablesDetail').text(tableStr.slice(0, -2));
    });

    modal.modal('show');
  }

  // Constructs UI that displays all the dataSources in this dashboard
  // given a mapping from dataSourceId to dataSource objects.
  function buildDataSourcesTable (dataSources) {
    // Clear the table first.
    $('#dataSourcesTable > tbody tr').remove();
    const dataSourcesTable = $('#dataSourcesTable > tbody')[0];

    // Add an entry to the dataSources table for each dataSource.
    for (let dataSourceId in dataSources) {
      const dataSource = dataSources[dataSourceId];

      let newRow = dataSourcesTable.insertRow(dataSourcesTable.rows.length);
      let nameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
      let refreshCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
      let infoCell = newRow.insertCell(2);

      let refreshButton = document.createElement('button');
      refreshButton.innerHTML = ('Refresh Now');
      refreshButton.type = 'button';
      refreshButton.className = 'btn btn-primary';
      refreshButton.addEventListener('click', function () { refreshDataSource(dataSource); });

      let infoSpan = document.createElement('span');
      infoSpan.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign';
      infoSpan.addEventListener('click', function () { showModal(dataSource); });

      nameCell.innerHTML = dataSource.name;
      refreshCell.appendChild(refreshButton);
      infoCell.appendChild(infoSpan);
    }
  }
})();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my trex extension file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest manifest-version="0.1" xmlns="http://www.tableau.com/xml/extension_manifest">
  <dashboard-extension id="com.tableau.extensions.samples.datasources" extension-version="0.6.0">
    <default-locale>en_US</default-locale>
    <name resource-id="name"/>
    <description>DataSources Sample</description>
    <author name="tableau" email="github@tableau.com" organization="tableau" website="https://www.tableau.com"/>
    <min-api-version>0.8</min-api-version>
    <source-location>
      <url>http://MACHINE_NAME:3030/</url>
    </source-location>
    <icon>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</icon>
    <permissions>
      <permission>full data</permission>
    </permissions>
  </dashboard-extension>
  <resources>
    <resource id="name">
      <text locale="en_US">DataSources Sample</text>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

Do I have to do something on Tableau server side to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you are using http:// without localhost. That is not allowed. I'm not sure why the error message is so unhelpful, but it could be that the error coming back from server is not formatted well for the client error box. Hard to know without logs. :)

Try out either switching to hosting your extension from http://localhost or create a self-signed certificate with SAN, add that to your trust store and host from https:// instead.

Comment: That is correct. That exactly was an issue. They need to provide more friendlier message.